# NullReferenceException while creating new instance of a class

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception, static-constructor

The Error as far as I can tell is occurring at one of these line:

```
SomeClass foo = new SomeClass();
foo.getSomeStuff(id1,id2,id3, connectionString, UserName, Password, out html, out xml);
```

Here is what SomeClass basically looks like:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    private static System.AppDomain SomeDomain { get; set; }
    private static SomeUtility utility { get; set; }

    static SomeClass()
    {
        InitializeSomeClass();
    }


    private static void InitializeSomeClass()
    {
        //code here
        utility = (SomeUtility)SomeDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName, "SomeUtility");
    }

    public void getSomeStuff(int id1, int id2, int id3, string connectionString, string UserName, string Password, out string html, out string xml)
    {
        html = xml = "";
        utility.ExtractContent(id1, id2, id3, connectionString, UserName, Password, out html, out xml);
    }

}
```

I misread the Code when translating it to more general terms.  I have corrected it.  Does this make anymore sense?

I have very little experience with Static Constructors, but I my instinct tells me the problem might lie somewhere in there.

Comment: The error is in `SomeOtherClass.methodThatSetsUtility();` probably

Comment: Your line `html = xml = "";` is not needed, because the method call right after it has `out` parameters that set both of these variables.

Comment: I agree with leppie.  Chances are methodThatSetsUtility(); is returning null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I found the issue.  It is occurring in a 3rd party assembly in the section: "//code here".  I didn't include the code earlier for security purposes, but I'll work with the 3rd party for resolution.  Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

In your sample code, the `SomeDomain` property has never been initialized when you execute the following line:

```
utility = (SomeUtility)SomeDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(...)
```

More generally, look at the stack trace and/or run under a debugger - you'll soon see which line is failing and why.

Comment: Wish I could run under a debugger.  This is only happening on a client's server so best I can do is write Log statements to see where it's happening.  The Log statements go dark at the line mentioned above.  I can't get anything else to happen after SomeClass foo = new SomeClass();

Comment: What does the stack trace say? can you get a logged copy of the stack trace when the exception is thrown?